# Networkx Array of Business Connections

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to create a networkx graph mapping the business connections in our database. In other words, I would like every id (i.e. each individual business) to be a node, and I would like there to be line connecting the nodes that are 'connected'. A business is considered as connected with another if the lead_id and connection_id are associated together as per the below data structure.

```
lead_id   connection_id
56340     1
56340     2
58684     3
58696     4
58947     5
```

Every example I find on the networkx documentation uses the following

```
G=nx.random_geometric_graph(200,0.125)
pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')
```

I am trying to determine how to incorporate my values into this.

Comment: Every example you found uses a random geometric probability graph to create it? Take a look at the tutorial to create a graph: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to create a graph from the data presented:

```
G = nx.Graph()
for node in zip(data.lead_id,data.connection_id):
    G.add_edge(node[0],node[1])
```

[image]